# Django image doesn't show up in template

Tags: django

I bought bootstrap theme and tried to apply it on my django project.

I almost done with it(css, js) except image files.

This is what it looks like :

[image]

Left one is my `django` project's view, right one is downloaded-source itself.  As you can see here, `css`, `js` work well but only image doesn't show up.

`setting.py`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'collect_static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'collect_media')
```

My project tree :

```
├── chacha_dabang
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── intro
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── intro
│   │       └── index.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── animate.min.css
│   │   ├── blue.css
│   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   │   ├── gray.css
│   │   ├── green.css
│   │   ├── main.css
│   │   ├── navy.css
│   │   ├── orange.css
│   │   ├── owl.carousel.css
│   │   ├── owl.transitions.css
│   │   ├── pink.css
│   │   ├── purple.css
│   │   └── red.css
│   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── fontello
│   │   │   ├── fontello-.eot
│   │   │   ├── fontello-circle.eot
│   │   │   ├── fontello-circle.svg
│   │   │   ├── fontello-circle.ttf
│   │   │   ├── fontello-circle.woff
│   │   │   ├── fontello-social-.eot
│   │   │   ├── fontello-social.eot
│   │   │   ├── fontello-social.svg
│   │   │   ├── fontello-social.ttf
│   │   │   ├── fontello-social.woff
│   │   │   ├── fontello.eot
│   │   │   ├── fontello.svg
│   │   │   ├── fontello.ttf
│   │   │   └── fontello.woff
│   │   └── fontello.css
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── art
│   │   │   ├── client01.jpg
│   │   │   ├── client02.jpg
│   │   │   ├── client03.jpg
│   │   │   ├── client04.jpg
│   │   │   ├── client05.jpg
│   │   │   ├── client06.jpg
│   │   │   ├── client07.jpg
│   │   │   ├── client08.jpg
│   │   │   ├── client09.jpg
│   │   │   ├── client10.jpg
│   │   │   ├── client11.jpg
│   │   │   ├── client12.jpg
│   │   │   ├── human01.jpg
│   │   │   ├── human02.jpg
│   │   │   ├── human03.jpg
│   │   │   ├── human04.jpg
│   │   │   ├── human05.jpg
│   │   │   ├── human06.jpg
│   │   │   ├── humans01.jpg
│   │   │   ├── image-background01.jpg
│   │   │   ├── image-background02.jpg
│   │   │   ├── image-background03.jpg
│   │   │   ├── image-background04.jpg
│   │   │   ├── office01.jpg
│   │   │   ├── office02.jpg
│   │   │   ├── office03.jpg
│   │   │   ├── pattern-background01.jpg
│   │   │   ├── pattern-background02.png
│   │   │   ├── pattern-background03.png
│   │   │   ├── photograph01-lg.jpg
│   │   │   ├── photograph02.jpg
│   │   │   ├── photograph03.jpg
│   │   │   ├── photograph04-lg.jpg
│   │   │   ├── product01.jpg
│   │   │   ├── product02.jpg
│   │   │   ├── product03.jpg
│   │   │   ├── product04.jpg
│   │   │   ├── product05.jpg
│   │   │   ├── product06.jpg
│   │   │   ├── screen-container.png
│   │   │   ├── service01.jpg
│   │   │   ├── slider01.jpg
│   │   │   ├── slider02.jpg
│   │   │   ├── slider03.jpg
│   │   │   ├── slider04.jpg
│   │   │   ├── slider05.jpg
│   │   │   ├── slider06.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work01-lg.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work01.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work02-lg.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work02.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work03.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work04.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work05.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work05a.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work06-lg.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work06.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work07.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work08-lg.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work08.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work08a-lg.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work08a.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work08b-lg.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work08b.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work08c-lg.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work08c.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work08d-lg.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work08d.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work08e.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work08f-lg.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work08f.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work08g-lg.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work09-lg.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work09.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work10.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work11.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work12.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work13.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work14-lg.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work15-lg.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work15.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work16-lg.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work16.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work17.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work18.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work19.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work20.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work21.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work22.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work23.jpg
│   │   │   ├── work24.jpg
│   │   │   └── work25.jpg
│   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   ├── grabbing.png
│   │   ├── logo-white.svg
│   │   └── logo.svg
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js
│   │   ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   │   ├── google.maps.api.v3.js
│   │   ├── html5shiv.js
│   │   ├── jquery.easing.1.3.min.js
│   │   ├── jquery.easytabs.min.js
│   │   ├── jquery.form.js
│   │   ├── jquery.isotope.min.js
│   │   ├── jquery.min.js
│   │   ├── jquery.validate.min.js
│   │   ├── owl.carousel.min.js
│   │   ├── respond.min.js
│   │   ├── scripts.js
│   │   ├── skrollr.min.js
│   │   ├── skrollr.stylesheets.min.js
│   │   ├── viewport-units-buggyfill.js
│   │   ├── waypoints-sticky.min.js
│   │   └── waypoints.min.js
│   └── switchstylesheet
│       └── switchstylesheet.js
├── templates
│   └── base.html
└── views
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
    │   └── home.cpython-35.pyc
    └── home.py
```

This is one of empty image html element showing up in `Chrome` development tool:
[image]

And corresponding template source code :

```
<div class="col-sm-6 inner-right-xs text-right">
     <figure><img src="{% static 'images/art/product01.jpg' %}" alt=""></figure>
</div>
```

(There is `{% load staticfiles %}` on the  top of template)

This is `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from views.home import Home
# import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', Home.as_view(), name='home'),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is log when runserver : `python manage.py runserver`:

```
(chacha_dabang) Chois@Chois-MacPro chacha_dabang $python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have unapplied migrations; your app may not work properly until they are applied.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

August 02, 2016 - 10:47:40
Django version 1.9.8, using settings 'chacha_dabang.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 48896
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:44] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:44] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:44] "GET /static/css/owl.carousel.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:44] "GET /static/css/green.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:44] "GET /static/css/animate.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:44] "GET /static/css/owl.transitions.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:44] "GET /static/fonts/fontello.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:44] "GET /static/images/logo.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:44] "GET /static/images/art/product01.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:44] "GET /static/images/art/product02.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:44] "GET /static/images/art/product03.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:44] "GET /static/images/art/slider01.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:44] "GET /static/images/art/work01.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:44] "GET /static/images/art/work02.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /static/images/art/work03.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /static/images/art/work04.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /static/images/art/work05.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /static/images/art/work06.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /static/images/art/work07.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /static/images/art/product04.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /static/images/art/product05.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /static/images/art/product06.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /static/images/art/slider02.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /static/images/logo-white.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /static/images/art/slider03.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /static/images/art/slider04.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /static/images/art/slider05.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /static/images/art/image-background04.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /static/css/blue.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /static/css/red.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /static/css/pink.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /static/css/purple.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /static/css/orange.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /static/css/navy.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /static/css/gray.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /assets/fonts/fontello/fontello.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 48896
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /assets/fonts/fontello/fontello-social.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 48896
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /assets/fonts/fontello/fontello.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 48896
[02/Aug/2016 10:47:45] "GET /assets/fonts/fontello/fontello-social.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 48896
```

Comment: According to logs, Django works fine. Try to open /static/images/art/product01.jpg in separate tab\window.

Comment: Oh, I checked my image folders, I got this many of 'R' shape images in there!! I don't know why but original source also has these 'R' shape images .... but when I open index.html in this original source code, 'R' shape image doens't show up! .. what a confused!

Comment: And also, in a log, "/assets/fonts/fontello/fontello.ttf", I don't have folder named 'assets' in my project dir, but it says HTTP 200, which means success!. Why does it happen?

Comment: Ok, it was my fault. They are supplying empty images at first!